# use variable's content as attachment in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to do this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->AddAttachment('text in file', 'file.txt');
```

so the attachment can have dynamic content. I can only use real file as attachment now. Obviously, real file is static, I want to generate some content dynamically and attach it to the mail. There must be some way to do it, I guess it's not that obscure feature. Someone knows how?

Comment: you mean you want to how to create file then insert dynamic content then attach it?

Comment: @Aboodred1 I hope there's more elegant solution than putting that content into a file, just for the attachment. See, I don't need the data in file, I just want to send it in a mail as a file, then discard that data. Obviously, I can put it in file, send it and then delete the file, but it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMailer attachment, doing it without a physical file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164167/phpmailer-attachment-doing-it-without-a-physical-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($string,$filename,$encoding,$type);
```

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial#3

Comment: Whoa, didn't see that one. Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for.