# How can I send a Google Maps by email?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In my angular webapp I store the lat and lon of a position.
I need to send an email to a user with some information including a Google Maps with a mark in (lat, lon) and some style for the maps like the zoom.
How can I include a Google Maps in my email with a mark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous project I had a similar requirement.

I made use of the google maps static API, which returns an IMG by request.

[Static API Doc´s](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?hl=en)

Now you have to decide if you wish to save the IMG to the filesystem and send it then via email, or if you just the IMG string and use this for your email.

If you wish to do it without saving the IMG to the filesystem take a look here:

[Embed Image in Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591393/embed-image-in-mail-without-having-pysical-image-file)

Otherwise it would be a normal email, how to do that is pretty good explained the Doc´s.

Good Luck!